# ADAL username/password flow in .net standard 1.4

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I'm trying to port a powershell module to .Net standard. One thing I notice is that the UserPasswordCredential class is not present in the .Net standard library. Is it not possible to perform a username/password flow login using adal in .Net Standard/Core?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `UserPasswordCredential` [is not available](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/commit/4193ea2d02cf1c45e0653b1401a20e7806805970) for .Net Core. However, as a workaround you can construct the HTTP request directly. More detail, you can refer the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498384/adal-v3-how-to-authenticate-using-userpasswordcredential).