# Windows Store 8.1 App Azure ADAL offline client authetication

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm building a Windows 8.1 store app and need to incorporate authentication.  This is an enterprise app used in house.  We load the app onto a tablet and a team may check that tablet out for weeks at a time, go out to the field to collect data and then we put in on a shelf until another team needs to use it.  Now different teams may work for difference clients so when we authenticate users not only do they get access to the app but we also check what groups they are in to determine what clients they can work on or what previous records they can search for.

I've followed various ADAL tutorials and am able to setup everything in Azure and in my app I am able to authenticate a user successfully and get their groups.  This relies on ADAL handling the username/password.  What happens when the app shuts down and the user in a place where there is no internet (or even a reliable cell connection)?  Specifically how can I have the user type a username/password to re-authenticate and get the same groups they were in when they can't access Azure services?

It appears they isn't available as the guidance always points to that is a risky proposition to have the app handle username/passwords.  I understand that stance and can appreciate the caution behind it.  However, in all of the ADAL documentation that I find that says this, none of them tell me how to handle an offline authentication scenario.

I have found links such as [ADAL v3: How to authenticate using UserPasswordCredential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498384/adal-v3-how-to-authenticate-using-userpasswordcredential) that tell me how to bypass the ADAL login page.  I may have to move to that route and handle all of the username/passwords securely within the app, but first I would like to reach out and see how others tackle this scenario.  Is it really as simple as avoiding best practices and just handle the username/password within the app?

If anyone has some guidance, ADAL (or other oauth providers) documentation, or other articles/advice I can follow up on to help achieve offline authentication I would greatly appreciate it!

Additional Information:

My scenario that I'm trying to cover is what happens when I have 1 device, 1 app, and many different users?  These users will be in different groups that will determine how data fields get populated (filter data in combo boxes) and what previously submitted forms they can query for.  All users would need to login when online to cache their information (say on Day 0) before they can ever use the app.  On Day 1 user 1 uses the app and doesn't log out.  I would expect the app to have a timeout timer to log that user out after 2 hours of no activity.  On Day 2, user 2 just grabs the device off the shelf and takes it out into the field.  He has no internet and needs to log in to determine who they are and what group they are in.  I would expect since he has logged in once and verified his credentials already that we can enable this sort of scenario.

What I'm looking for is guidance if ADAL as a library can handle this or is it truly up to me the app developer to handle this sort of scenario.  As I see it currently I need to store all user credentials, but at the same time it seems like everyone advises against that.  I feel like I'm in a situation where I need to create a custom login screen and store the user data, SECURELY of course, even though its not recommended.  It seems like all articles on how to use ADAL are written from a consumer app standpoint (or a BYOD) and don't take into account how a mobile app would be written for the enterprise.

Comment: That depends on how you treat the token , If app offline and re-connect after a while , you could get the token from somewhere and check whether it is expired , if not , you could still use that token .

Comment: I have a user that is required to login with the app online the first time.  During that initial sign on I would like to store their groups, and user info I can get from the graph API to make offline login work.  The next day that user goes out into the field (no internet available) and there isn't a non expired token cached.  This requires them to enter their credentials again.  How can I have that person log in with a username/password again?  To me ADAL only works in this scenario via UserPassworedCredentail which means I need to handle saving that user credentials in a local data store.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your app design, if the first time(app online) , user login and app store all groups ,user information .After that user doesn't need to use token to get related information again(send request to server to acquire groups/user info). If app is offline , user doesn't need to re-authenticate(app controls the user session) , just get group/user information from cache . When using resource owner flow , you still need to send authenticate request to Azure AD server which need internet.

Comment: Please read the "Additional comments" part of my original post.  I've explained my scenario in more detail as to why I don't think that will work.  The guidance you have given me makes a lot of sense for a consumer based or BYOD enterprise app.

Comment: Your scenario should be controlled with your code . 1) when has internet , user could use ADAL to login with azure ad , get all user/group information to your own database . 2) when has no internet ,your app need to login new user by check user credentials in your own database , you can't use ADAL since that need internet to communicate with Azure AD 3) your app controls user session, you could logout user who has no activity after 2h . Your  scenario should control user credentials check in your app when offline .