# Authenticate and get Azure AD token in .net core Web API with grant_type as Password

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

How to configure Azure AD authentication and get access token in .net core Web API with `grant_type:password` mechanism? without re-redirecting azure portal.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) { 
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => { // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request. 
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is possible if you directly send post request to token endpoint as shown in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40499342/5751404) .

But the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant is **Not Recommended** as it's less secure than the other flows(your application handles the credentials), and it is not compatible with conditional access . In addition , personal accounts that are invited to an Azure AD tenant can't use ROPC. Also ,If users need to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to log in to the application, they will be blocked instead.

-------Suggest approach

If the scenario is user has been authenticated on an client application ,and also acquires an access token to access your web api , in web api , you need to call another resource/API , you can use the [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) which enables an application that invokes a service or web API to pass user authentication to another service or web API.  Your can click [here](https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-aspnet-core) for code sample in .Net Core .

You can also use the [OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) permits a web service (confidential client) to use its own credentials instead of impersonating a user, to authenticate when calling another web service . You can click [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2) for code sample .

Comment: How to implement Single .net core Web API get the user credential from user and pass it to Azure AD for Authentication? based on Azure token it has to allow user to access other API.

Comment: How do you get the user's credential in a web api application ? You will create login page yourself in web api ?

Comment: Yes, Is there better method to get Azure AD access token at web API? Is that .net core WEB API remember user token for each other web API call ? Any better way can you suggest..

Comment: In your scenario , password flow seems the opinion since you need user's identity .