# Azure AD oAuth skips 2FA and failed with AADSTS50076 error code

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory

I configured Azure AD oAuth flow and it works well, but from time to time for different users, it skip 2FA check on the azure side and fails with an error:

> AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.

I can't find any configuration feature to force 2FA or so even on the Azure side neither on the API configuration. Could someone advise why it can happen or how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it may be blocked if they try to use the MFA, which is answered in the below SO thread.

Reference SO Thread: [Authenticate and get Azure AD token in .net core Web API with grant_type as Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215795/authenticate-and-get-azure-ad-token-in-net-core-web-api-with-grant-type-as-pass)