# Power Bi integration with ASP.NET WEB FORMS updated with the new API V2

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, powerbi

I need to integrate a power bi reports of my workspace, i have already done it with the embed tool provided by Microsoft but the project is developed in MVC structure and i want it with WEB FORMS integration. I don't now if there is an updated program with the current API of Power Bi for Web forms.

using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2;

Comment: Why would the integration be any different in webforms do you suppose? You can use HTML there just the same as in an MVC view. Have you encountered an specific issue when trying to embed the code?

Comment: @ADyson its just the userPasswordCredential compatibility i dont know how i can get token form azure, i tried many solutions like these 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498384/adal-v3-how-to-authenticate-using-userpasswordcredential  and https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/problem-getting-authentication-token-from-AAD/td-p/333691  , thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Simply I add a POST request to access token credential in order to obtain the token. This problem is due to the incompatibility with the UserPasswordCredential function.

```
private void getTokenUrl()
    {
        var url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?";
        var client = new WebClient();
        var method = "POST"; 
        var parameters = new NameValueCollection();

        parameters.Add("grant_type", "password");
        parameters.Add("scope", "openid");
        parameters.Add("resource", ResourceUrl);
        parameters.Add("client_id", ApplicationId);
        parameters.Add("username", Username);
        parameters.Add("password", Password);

        var response_data = client.UploadValues(url, method, parameters);

        var responseString = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(response_data);
        var Request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(responseString);
        string tok = Request.access_token;
        tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(tok, "Bearer");
    }
```