# Azure AD API For Command Line Based SAML2 SSO (for AWS federated login)

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, aws-sts

I am trying to write a command line program (CLI in Go) that should work similar to this:

1. User submits her Azure AD username/password credentials to the CLI.
2. The CLI uses the credentials to authenticate against Azure, which returns either a token or another challenge for the end user (e.g., MFA).
3. If another challenge is returned, the CLI waits for input from the user (e.g., MFA code) and submits the input to Azure AD MFA input. If successful, Azure AD returns a token.
4. The CLI submits the returned token & SAML2 request to Azure AD SAML endpoint and gets back from Azure AD a SAML2 response.
5. The CLI then submits the SAML2 response to AWS SAML endpoint and gets back AWS IAM temporary credentials.

Thanks,

Yossi C.

Answer (score 1):

Not gonna pretend I'm a super-expert in this field, but here's what I know:
The scenario you describe *used* to be supported by the Azure AD C# sdk, but that was removed. Azure AD really wants you to authenticate either using the "regular" browser-based login flow or using so-called "device code" (try the azure cli locally to see how it works). Depending on how your directory is set up, Azure AD *might* have to pass your request on to a downstream auth service (for example if the directory is setup with ADFS/saml auth) instead of handling it itself. By "hard-coding" the username/password logic inside your cli, your essentially limiting your tool to work only with Azure AD directories that are configured so that authentication is local and doesn't have to be forwarded.

All that said: Constructing the necessary http calls aren't super-advanced. I ended up using the Azure Powershell module and set up a http proxy locally so that I could inspect the auth calls, and it's fairly straight-forward. There's also some more information in the links provided here: [ADAL username/password flow in .net standard 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497937/adal-username-password-flow-in-net-standard-1-4)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Trondh! SAML2 is required for various reasons, does ADAL fits for the job? I did not find evidence for that. I understand your point about using username/password but in our case, we enable interactive SSO, we support multiple IdPs (forward/proxy is not expected nor desired), and we also wish to connect the SSO to an MFA (less manageable/feasible in cases where the authN is forwarded), thus, the username/password method seems to make sense. We may consider client-certificate as well for non-interactive flows but that's a completely different story ;)

Comment: ah of course. I was thinking you only needed to get an authenticated session with Azure AD, but ofc you need the saml token becuase your using Azure AD as saml Idp. Azure AD can definitely talk SAML, but it might require the non-free version.

Answer (score 1):

The aws-azure-login CLI utility does the login by instantiating a headless browser to access the Azure AD sign-in page. You should study their source code.

https://github.com/dtjohnson/aws-azure-login

Comment: Thanks a lot Myron, and it works really well too! I am on it already "compiling" them into GoLang :)